# Firebase Admin Java implementation gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Admin to write data into my realtime data base.

I've followed the document of firebase.

Below are steps I followed .

Added dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Initialized SDK as bellow

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path to json");
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount)).setDatabaseUrl("https://paylahmerchantapp.firebaseio.com").build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

When I run the code in the main method I'm getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/util/Utils
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.<init>(FirebaseOptions.java:120)
    at com.example.demo.PostFirebaseApplication.main(PostFirebaseApplication.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: run mvn dependency:tree or mvn dependency:list to check if maven has pulled down the required dependency google-api-client, if not add it to your pom file

Comment: google-api-client-1.22.0.jar is part of my Maven dependencies.

Comment: how do you run "main method"? from within IDE or through command line? It could be a classpath issue

Comment: I'm running it from IDE.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: i faced the same issue 4 years after this question was posted :(